# Oracle check column in row before for a match

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a query where I find a match on the substring of two different columns.   I can get my results with a "with" table and then querying those results but it is slow.
    Row2 is what the search condition will look for.   To simplifiy Row2 
    columnC=1
    Row2 columnB holds the value that the substring is taken out of to check to 
    see if the Row1 columnA subtring= Row2 columnB substring.
Any advice or thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use LAG() for this purpose (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm)).  Example:

Table & data

```
create table t1 ( column_a, column_b  )
as
select 'string100', 'string200' from dual union
select 'string200', 'string100' from dual union
select 'string300', 'string100' from dual union
select 'string400', 'string500' from dual union
select 'string500', 'string400' from dual ;
```

Find "preceding" values with LAG()

```
select
  column_a
, column_b
, lag ( column_a, 1, 0 ) over ( order by column_a ) preceding_a
from t1 ;

COLUMN_A   COLUMN_B   PRECEDING_A  
string100  string200  0            
string200  string100  string100    
string300  string100  string200    
string400  string500  string300    
string500  string400  string400
```

Final query and results

```
-- Check: is Row1 columnA subtring = Row2 columnB substring
select column_a, column_b,
  case
    when substr( preceding_a, 7, 1 ) = substr( column_b, 7, 1 ) then
      'substring Row1 columnA = substring Row2 columnB'
    else
      'substrings don''t match'
  end compare_substrings
from (
  select
    column_a
  , column_b
  , lag ( column_a, 1, 0 ) over ( order by column_a ) preceding_a
  from t1
) ;

COLUMN_A   COLUMN_B   COMPARE_SUBSTRINGS                               
string100  string200  substrings don't match                           
string200  string100  substring Row1 columnA = substring Row2 columnB  
string300  string100  substrings don't match                           
string400  string500  substrings don't match                           
string500  string400  substring Row1 columnA = substring Row2 columnB
```

You can probably make the "final query" more compact (ie without writing an inline view).  [Dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ed9feabad5071935a5dae9a15936e076).